# Ordering a list of fractions and mixed numbers

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, fractions

I am looking for a way that would allow me to have a column that I would simply manually input a number and then the list would sort itself based off this list, this would be using c# as the language for the listing and it's ms SQL

I don't have much information, but if anyone wants to know anything else feel free to ask and I will try and answer to my best ability.

They are currently stored as strings.

The thing that causes it to get thrown out is because some of the lists contains ranges but some contain fractions, both which are displayed the same I.E 1/2 can mean 1-2 or 1/2(half)

All of the SQL connection is done using NHibernate.

The reason for not simply sorting it normally, is that the list is ordered using fractions currently and the list works fine, however when it gets over 1, it seems to break and throws all of them to the bottom of the list I.E:

[image: Image List]

Example of how I would like this to work:

I would have a column in my database named "DisplayOrder" or something along those lines.

Database row says "1", this would be the first item in a list to appear.
Database row says "8", this would be the 8th item in the list to appear.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: are you just trying to sort a list?  any reason why you would do that with a database?  are there any duplicates in this list?

Comment: I would suggest you do this in you db query order by DisplayOrder asc

Comment: The issue is that how it is currently sorted can't be done as for some reason fractions seem to break it.

Comment: @Norton Taylor are you storing fractions in a character field?

Comment: They are currently stored as strings, yes.

Comment: 2008, does it matter? :p

Comment: @NortonTaylor yes, in a *lot* of cases it does. If you're being asked for more information, don't question it, because it is usually for a good reason, not just to badger you. To prevent this in the future, please always tag your question with the version(s) you need to support. You can [read more about this here](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/).

Comment: How does 1/2 mean 1-2? How is software supposed to determine which one you meant? Are you planning to manually populate this `DisplayOrder` column? If not, what is the purpose of *storing* it, since you'll have to update it every time any data in the table changes?

Comment: I didn't actually write this part of the code, so I am unsure how it properly works. It doesn't seem logical to me but it must have to the programmer at the  time. I have decided that I am going to do this a simpler way, we actually have a custom decimal area that you can set within a products details, so I have decided to allow them to manually set this decimal and order by this.

Comment: @NortonTaylor Do you have (or can calculate) the actual numeric **values** of these fractions? What you have now is not a value, its just a string representation. Also, how do you define order between dimensioned and dimension-less quantities? For example 1" has dimension "length" and 1/2 has no dimension. How do you compare them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a quick function to parse your fractions and convert them to floats, which can then be used for comparison and sorting.  You may need more in the "sanitation" step, possibly normalizing whitespace, removing other characters, etc., and may have to check the divisor for zero (only you know your data).

```
create function dbo.FractionToFloat(@fraction varchar(100))
returns float
as
begin
    declare @input varchar(100)
        , @output float
        , @whole int
        , @dividend int
        , @divisor int

    -- Sanitize input
    select @input = ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(@fraction, '''', ''), '"', '')))

    select @whole = cast(case
        when charindex('/', @input) = 0 then @input
        when charindex(' ', @input) = 0 then '0'
        else left(@input, charindex(' ', @input) - 1)
        end as int)

    select @dividend = cast(case
        when charindex('/', @input) = 0 then '0'
        when charindex(' ', @input) = 0 then left(@input, charindex('/', @input) - 1)
        else substring(@input, charindex(' ', @input) + 1, charindex('/', @input) - charindex(' ', @input) - 1)
        end as int)

    select @divisor = cast(case
        when charindex('/', @input) = 0 then '1'
        else right(@input, charindex('/', reverse(@input)) - 1)
        end as int)

    select @output = cast(@whole as float) + (cast(@dividend as float) / cast(@divisor as float))

    return @output
end
```

This way, you can simply order by the function's output like so:

```
select *
from MyTable
order by dbo.FractionToFloat(MyFractionColumn)
```

I wouldn't normally suggest rolling your own parser that you have to maintain as the data changes, but this seems simple enough on the surface, and probably better than manually maintaining an ordinal column.  Also, if you had to compare various units (feet to inches, minutes to seconds), then this gets more complicated.  I'm removing anything that looks like a unit in your demo data.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting result seems perfectly normal, since I really think that the database doesn't understand what "1 1/4" means.
Which type has your database field? Text/varchar/string I guess?

Maybe you should create a stored proc to convert the fraction values to numeric ones, an then call

```
SELECT field1, field2, ParseAndConvertProc(DisplayOrder) as disp_order ORDER by disp_order
```

Comment: I have a default sorting method at the minute that works fine until it gets into the ranges of the products so we have a product that is 1/2(half) but then they are also displayed as a range which is 1/2 (1-2), I think the best way about going around fixing this would be to simply check if the column is empty and if it is to just order by the default order.

Comment: This wouldn't work due to the fractions and ranges displayed differently.

Comment: Yes, this is part of the problem. Let me sum up to see if I've understood everything: the problem seems to be that   1) your fraction values are stored as text (which makes it impossible to parse as fraction values by SQL-server without explicit help/proc)    2) your values doesn't have a constant syntax scheme : sometimes '/', sometimes '-', sometimes '1 1/2' instead of '3/2'. Am I wrong?

Comment: I believe the best way to sort this issue would be to simply check if the database column has numbers in it and if does, to sort by that opposed to the default method.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring for the moment that `1/2` can mean `between 1 and 2`, you can deal with the madness and try to get some order out of it.

```
CREATE TABLE #Fractions (
   Frac varchar(15)
);

INSERT #Fractions VALUES
   ('1 1/2'), ('1 1/4'), ('1"'), ('1/2'), ('1/4'), ('1/8'),
   ('2 1/2'), ('2"'), ('3"'), ('3/4'), ('3/8'), ('4"');

WITH Canonical AS (
   SELECT
      Frac,
      F,
      CharIndex(' ', F) S,
      CharIndex('/', F) D
   FROM
      (SELECT Frac, Replace(Frac, '"', '') F FROM #Fractions) F
   WHERE
      F NOT LIKE '%[^0-9 /]%'
), Parts AS (
   SELECT
      Frac,
      Convert(int, Left(F, CASE WHEN D = 0 THEN Len(F) ELSE S END)) W,
      Convert(int, CASE WHEN D > 0 THEN Substring(F, S + 1, D - S - 1) ELSE '' END) N,
      Convert(int, CASE WHEN D > 0 THEN Substring(F, D + 1, 2147483647) ELSE '1' END) D
   FROM Canonical
)
SELECT
   Frac,
   W + N * 1.0 / D Calc
FROM Parts
ORDER BY Calc;

DROP TABLE #Fractions;
```

But I don't recommend this. Use my query as a base to get the correct value, and switch to using decimal values.

Note you also have to search your data for characters this code didn't account for, using the pattern match above with LIKE instead of NOT LIKE. Then remove them or account for them somehow.

If what you said is true that `1/2` can mean two things, andyou can tell the difference between them, then you can do something about it. Store the range in two columns. If they are the same then there is no range.

If you can't tell the difference between the two meanings then you're just majorly messed up and may as well quit your job and go race sled dogs in Alaska.